# Appending large amount of data to a tables (HDF5) database where database.numcols != newdata.numcols?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, pytables

I am trying to append a large dataset (>30Gb) to an existing pytables table.  The table is N columns, and the dataset is N-1 columns; one column is calculated after I know the other N-1 columns.

I'm using `numpy.fromfile()` to read chunks of the dataset into memory before appending it to the database.  Ideally, I'd like to stick the data into the database, then calculate the final column, and finish up by using `Table.modifyColumn()` to complete the operation.

I've considered appending `numpy.zeros((len(new_data), N))` to the table, then using `Table.modifyColumns()` to fill in the new data, but I'm hopeful someone knows a nice way to avoid generating a huge array of empty data for each chunk that I need to append.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why not just append a column of zeros?  np.zeros(len(new_data, 1))

Comment: I'm confused too.  To what are you suggesting I append a column of zeros?

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?  I think I now understand that you're using numpy to read data from an hdf5 file and PyTables to manipulate a (different?) hdf5 file?  Why not extend the array with numpy .concatenate before inserting into Tables?  I guess I'm not sure what your goals are.

Comment: I'm reading slices of binary data from a file. The file is too large to manipulate (easily) with `numpy` (AFAIK), so I'm copying the data into an HDF5 file, so I can use the `tables` module to manipulate the data.  Each slice that I read is 2^26 bytes.  My main goal is to avoid unnecessary copying of the data.  Doesn't `numpy.concatenate` create a copy of the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns are all the same type, you can use `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to make the array you read from the file of shape (L, N-1) to look like shape (L, N).  For example,

```
In [5]: a = numpy.arange(12).reshape(4,3)

In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

In [7]: a.strides
Out[7]: (24, 8)

In [8]: b = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(4, 4), strides=(24, 8))

In [9]: b
Out[9]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  3,   4,   5,   6],
       [  6,   7,   8,   9],
       [  9,  10,  11, 112]])
```

Now you can use this array `b` to fill up the table.  The last column of each row will be the same as the first column of the next row, but you'll overwrite them when you can compute the values.

This won't work if `a` is record array (i.e. has a complex dtype).  For that, you can try `numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields`.  As it will copy the data to a new array, it won't save you any significant amount of memory, but it will allow you to do all the writing at once.

Comment: Is b using the same memory as a?  If so I'm in business! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `b` uses the same memory as `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the results to another table.  Unless there's some compelling reason for the calculated column to be adjacent to the other columns, that's probably the easiest.  There's something to be said for separating raw data from calculations anyways.

If you must increase the size of the table, look into using [h5py](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/).  It provides a more direct interface to the h5 file.  Keep in mind that depending on how the data set was created in the h5 file, it may not be possible to simply append a column to the data.  See section 1.2.4, "Dataspace" in http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/03_DataModel.html for a discussion regarding the general data format.  h5py supports [resize](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/wiki/FAQ#Appending_data_to_a_dataset) if the underlying dataset supports it.

You could also use a single buffer to store the input data like so:

```
z = zeros((nrows, N))
while more_data_in_file:
    # Read a data block
    z[:,:N-1] = fromfile('your_params')
    # Set the final column
    z[:,N-1:N] = f(z[:,:N-1])
    # Append the data
    tables_handle.append(z)
```

Comment: There are compelling reasons to keep everything together.  The data is analogous to "time" and "samples", where "time" is the computed value.  I'll look into h5py.

Comment: Thanks for the updated response.  I'm not sure why I thought I had to generate the dummy data on each pass...